# Load text in text view from RAW resource

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

i want to click on button in first activity and in second activity load text from raw resource into textview. i think its possible via `putextra` , `getextra` method. my text reader code to textview is this.

```
 TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_data);

    String data = readTextFile(this, R.raw.books);
    textView.setText(data);
}

public static String readTextFile(Context ctx, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try 
    {
        while (( line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        return null;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

any one can help me

Answer (score 2):

Please Use below code for Read file data from raw folder.

```
try {
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.books);

    byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
    in_s.read(b);
    textView.setText(new String(b));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    textView.setText("Error: can't show help.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So on button click in first activity you call an intent starting second Activity. If you want in your first activity to choose the resource id, then i advice you to use something like this

```
Button button = (Button) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("resource_id", R.raw.books); //R.raw.books or any other resource you want to display
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Then in your second activity you get this data like this

```
int resourceId = getIntent().getIntExtra("resource_id");
```

And you use this `resourceId` instead of `R.raw.books`